# default value for form:select

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc

In my current spring project, I have a form which have this input field:

```
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <form:label path="${entry.key}">${entry.key}</form:label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form:select path="${entry.key}.id" class="form-control">
                                <form:options items="${values[entry.key]}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="nome"/>
                            </form:select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I want add to this a default value, in case the user don't want select an option (the atribute can be null in the database). I try this:

1-

```
<form:option value="-" label="--Please Select"/>
```

2-

```
<form:option value="" label="--Please Select"/>
```

3-

```
<form:option value="" label="--Please Select" disabled="disabled"/>
```

but none of this options work (I get an error

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.spring.loja.model.categoria.persistence.model.Categoria
```

when I run the application).

Anyone can tell me what the right way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

2 of the entity classes from my project. The code above works fine with the first one (Product), but I get the error `TransientObjectException` when I try insert the second one (Order).

Entity class: Product

```
@Entity
@Table(name="produto")
public class Produto {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nome", unique=true)
    @Order(value=1)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="preco")
    @Order(value=2)
    private Float preco;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categoria")
    @Order(value=3)
    private Categoria categoria;

    @Column(name="resumo", length=140)
    @Order(value=4)
    private String resumo;

    @Column(name="descricao", length=65535)
    @Order(value=5)
    private String descricao;
}
```

entity class: Order

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pedido")
public class Pedido {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="cliente")
    @Order(value=1)
    private Cliente cliente;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="produto")
    @Order(value=2)
    private Produto produto;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="cobranca")
    @Order(value=3)
    private Cobranca cobranca;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I try this:

```
                            <form:select path="${entry.key}.id" class="form-control">
                                <form:option value="" label="--Please Select"/>
                                <form:options items="${values[entry.key]}"></form:options>
                            </form:select>
```

In this way, I get an error when I try insert a new value. With this:

```
                            <form:select path="${entry.key}" class="form-control">
                                <form:option value="" label="--Please Select"/>
                                <form:options items="${values[entry.key]}"></form:options>
                            </form:select>
```

I can insert a new item ONLY with when no option is selected. I try this for this entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pagina")
public class Pagina {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome", unique=true, nullable=false, length=32)
    @Order(value=1)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "titulo", nullable=false, length=32)
    @Order(value=2)
    private String titulo;

    @Column(name="resumo", length=140)
    @Order(value=3)
    private String resumo;

    @Column(name = "descricao", length=65535)
    @Order(value=4)
    private String descricao;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="pagina")
    @Order(value=5)
    private Pagina pagina;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="produto")
    @Order(value=6)
    private Produto produto;
}
```

Anyone can see what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure the cause of the TransientObjectException, but below is a simple example for how to set default value to form:select. Hope this helps.

**JSP:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form:form modelAttribute="myForm" method="post">
    <form:select path="valueOfSelectElement">
      <form:option value="default-value" label="--Please Select" />
      <form:options items="${options}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
    </form:select>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
package org.myorg.myapp;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView showForm() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("form");
    List<IdAndName> options = Arrays.asList(
        new IdAndName("id1", "name1"),
        new IdAndName("id2", "name2"),
        new IdAndName("id3", "name3")
    );
    mav.addObject("options", options);

    MyForm myForm = new MyForm();
    myForm.setValueOfSelectElement("default-value");
    mav.addObject("myForm", myForm);

    return mav;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String processForm(MyForm myForm) {
    return myForm.getValueOfSelectElement();
  }

  static class MyForm {
    private String valueOfSelectElement;

    public String getValueOfSelectElement() {
      return valueOfSelectElement;
    }

    public void setValueOfSelectElement(String valueOfSelectElement) {
      this.valueOfSelectElement = valueOfSelectElement;
    }
  }

  static class IdAndName {
    private String id;

    private String name;

    public IdAndName(String id, String name) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I add more one update to my question. I can insert a new item whe I use: `<form:select path="valueOfSelectElement">`, but this way if I select one option in the select, this option isn't saved. With something this: `<form:select path="valueOfSelectElement.id">`, I get the error I described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set default value to your select form, put selected="selected" attribute into your form:option tag. But I'm not sure that your org.hibernate.TransientObjectException somehow connected with that

Comment: This `selected` option already is put when the code is renderized. this code works for some entities, by the way, like the class Produto (Product) I add to my question, but don't work with the class Pedido (Order) also added above; in this case, I get the error with the atribute `cliente`.